# Why I can't load a user control to my toolbox in visual studio 2012 pro?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Im going to the toolbox and doing right click then choose items then im going to the COM Components tab then browse and my file name wich in this case is LineGraph.dll I see this file on my hard disk I also did properties on the file and I see that the type is .DLL

But when im trying to load/open it in the toobox im getting error: LineGraph.tlb could not be loaded.
But the file is .dll where from this .tlb came ?

[image]

Comment: I got this .dll file from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274318/Line-Graph-Component-in-Csharp I have downloaded the demo and there is there the dll file.

Comment: `.tlb` is a standalone binary file is made from `.dll`. Anyway do you see `.dll` file that you built, in your `projects bin/debug folder`? If you see it there, then right click on `Toolbox` -> click `Choose Items` and when the dialog comes up `click on browse`. Browse to where your `.dll` file is, and then it'll put it in that `list in the dialog`. Once you check it off in that dialog, it'll become available in your toolbox.

Comment: Yes just built it now and I see a dll file and yet im getting the same error.

Comment: :( that's then beyond me... hope an expert help, I am curious to know as well.. btw when you were creating the user control, did you use project template as `Class Library`?

Comment: Working my mistake I tried to load COM Compnent instead of .Net so when I browsed it was looking for tlb . Now it's working. Sorry.

Comment: That's great, then you can post it as answer for everyone's benefit :D

Answer (score 6):

Working my mistake I tried to load it as COM Component instead of .Net so when I browsed for the file it was looking for tlb . Now it's working.

Tool Box > Mouse Right Click Button > Choose Items > .Net  Framework Components

Wait some seconds until it will finish to load all the items then click on Browse on the right bottom corner select the .dll file and click ok.